# MapWithOverlaysActivity - Could not determine $(TargetFrameworkVersion)

Tags: android, google-maps, frameworks, google-api, xamarin

I have downloaded `Xamarin` Studio and am trying to use the MapsAndLocationDemo3 sample with the MapWithOverlaysActivity project.

I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA0000: Could not determine $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for API level '19.' (XA0000) (SimpleMapDemo)
```

In the `Android SDK Manager` I have installed all the options for `Android 4.4 (API 19)` as well as the Google Play services.

Can I please have some help to get this sample working?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully you've figured this out by now since it was posted quite some time ago.

I had this issue this evening. I was able to resolve it by opening the .csproj file in something like Notepad++, changing AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk from True to False, and rebuilding. If your issue is the same, hopefully this will help.

Comment: Alternatively this can be fixed by setting Target Framework in Options | Build/General to Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean). The root cause seems to be that Xamarin.Android only supports v18 right now, and you have v19 SDK components installed.

Comment: Didn't work for me, and I do have Android 7.0 (API 24 installed)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling my existing Xamarin.Android and reinstalling the latest fixed the this issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the correct version of the SDK installed.

In Xamarin Studio, go to the project options and click on General.  The Target framework field should show the version of the SDK that will be used to build the project.

If the SDK is not installed, the field will have something like Android X.Y (not installed).  From Xamarin Studio go to Tool > Open Android SDK Manager and make sure that you installed the required SDK.