# Xamarin forms android: Could not determine API level for $(TargetFrameworkVersion) of 'v8.1'

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Getting following error when rebuilding xamarin forms android project.

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA0000: Could not determine API level for $(TargetFrameworkVersion) of 'v8.1'. (XA0000) (Myproject.Android)

Found the same issue in some other threads. The solution on there is open .csproj file and change AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk from True to False, and rebuild. I found this solution on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650843/mapwithoverlaysactivity-could-not-determine-targetframeworkversion) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700389/xamarin-android-api-level-19-bug).

But I don't know which .csproj file need to modify? Can some one tell it more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to edit `Myproject.Android.csproj`.

Here's how to edit a `csproj` in Visual Studio:

## Visual Studio for Mac

[image: Visual Studio for Mac]

## Visual Studio on PC

### 1. Unload the Project

[image]

### 2. Edit the File

[image]

### 3. Reload the Project

[image]

Comment: My .csproj file don't have AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk lines, so I just add those linesinside of <PropertyGroup> :<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>False</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>

Comment: This is no longer a valid option, as AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk is deprecated.

Comment: Did you find a valid option? @Justin

Answer (score 0):

Just go to options and then general

[image]

then select appropriate target version